# Flux Density Unit Conversion

Tags: units, photons, flux

I am confused how to convert from ${\rm cm^{-2}\,s^{-1}\,Å^{-1}}$ to ${\rm erg\,cm^{-2}\,s^{-1}\,Å^{-1}}$. How do I do that?

Comment: The first is a number flux, while the second is an energy flux. So you need to know the energy of the photons.

Comment: Welcome to astronomy SE, I converted your units to a more readable format.

Comment: Don't be disheartened by the fact that your first question got immediately closed, I would be happy to vote for reopen if you edit in a bit more context where those units occur and what you are trying to do.